# How can I keep the gpu running for more than 12 hours in google colaboratory?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a model on google colaboratoy but the problem is that the GPU gets disconnected after 12 hours and hence I am not able to train my model beyond a certain point. Is there a way to keep GPU connected for longer times?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to run for more than 12 hours, but saving snapshots and continuing the training by loading the last snapshot is a good practice anyway.

Comment: @BlueSun I have similar problem. Could you plz provide a piece of code or something to save the snapshot of semi-trained model and restore it to train it again?

Comment: @yaminigoel https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model

Comment: Here is a guide on what BluSun suggested.

https://medium.com/@prajwal.prashanth22/google-colab-drive-as-persistent-storage-for-long-training-runs-cb82bc1d5b71